# Emacs Lisp: A list inside a mapcar

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm using a function that uses a mapcar to apply a (simple) function to all members of a list, like this :

```
(mapcar 'my-concat-function '(
                              "/path/one.php"
                              "/path/two.php"))
```

But I want to use `directory-files` to generate the file list and filter it, something like this :

```
(mapcar 'my-concat-function '(
                              (directory-files "/path/" nil "\\.php$")))
```

But I always get a

```
find-file-noselect: Wrong type argument: stringp, (directory-files "/path/" nil "\\.php$")
```

When I evaluate

```
(directory-files "/path/" nil "\\.php$")
```

It returns

```
("one.php" "two.php" "three.php" ...)
```

(**I did not add the "..."** ; Emacs did. No matter the size of the list, it seems to always end with "...")

Question :

How can I format the output of `directory-files` so that it produces exactly what mapcar wants, a single list of atoms, I don't really know how to call this form :

```
"one.php" "two.php" "three.php"
```

Without the parenthesis, and without those weird "..."?

EDIT

When I try the forms suggested (thank you guys) the quoted function as 1st arg of mapcar does not work (the regexp don't find anything, all files end up open in empty (?) buffers) anymore :(

Here is the full code, thank you very much for helping, it's weird, this function took very little time to write, and now i'm blocked since hours on this simple list issue, arg.

```
(defun px-bpm-parse (fname)
  "Extract elements. Basic Project Management."
  (setq in-buf (set-buffer (find-file fname)))
  (setq u1 '())
  (setq u2 '())
  (setq u3 '())
  (setq project-dir "/var/www/html/microlabel.git/")

  (beginning-of-buffer)

  (while
      (re-search-forward "^.*<link.*href=\"\\([^\"]+\\)\".*rel=\"stylesheet\"" nil t)
    (when (match-string 0)
      (setq url (match-string 1) )
      (setq u3 (cons (concat "[[file:" project-dir url "][" url "]]\n") u3))))
  (beginning-of-buffer)
  (while
      (re-search-forward "^.*<a.*href=\"\\([^\"]+\\)\"[^>]+>\\([^<]+\\)</a>" nil t)
    (when (match-string 0)
      (setq url (match-string 1) )
      (setq title (match-string 2) )
      (setq u1 (cons (concat "[[file:" project-dir url "][" title "]]\n") u1))))
  (beginning-of-buffer)
  (while
      (re-search-forward "^.*<script.*src=\"\\([^\"]+\\)\"" nil t)
    (when (match-string 0)
      (setq url (match-string 1) )
      (setq u2 (cons (concat "[[file:" project-dir url "][" url "]]\n") u2))))
  (beginning-of-buffer)

  (progn
    (with-current-buffer "BPM.org"
      (insert "** File: ")

      ;; (org-insert-link &optional COMPLETE-FILE LINK-LOCATION DEFAULT-DESCRIPTION)

      (insert fname)
      (insert "\n*** HREF Links (by name)\n")
      (mapcar 'insert u1)
      (insert "\n*** SCRIPT Links\n")
      (mapcar 'insert u2)
      (insert "\n*** CSS Links\n")
      (mapcar 'insert u3)
      (insert "\n\n"))
    (switch-to-buffer "BPM.org")
    (org-mode)))

(defun px-bpm ()
  ;; (defun px-bpm (prj-root)
  "List all links"
  (interactive)
  ;; (interactive "sEnter project root directory ")

  (progn

    (with-current-buffer (get-buffer-create "BPM.org")
      (insert "* File dependencies\n\n"))
    ;; (mapcar 'px-bpm-parse '(
                            ;; "/var/www/html/microlabel.git/add.php"
                            ;; ))

    (mapcar 'px-bpm-parse (directory-files "/var/www/html/microlabel.git/" nil "\\.php$"))
    ))
```

Comment: When you evaluate something, the evaluation message truncates if its long.  If you want to see it all, then do something like:  `(message "%s" (directory-files "/path/" nil "\\.php$"))`

Comment: It looks like you have an extra set of parentheses and a quote that are getting in the way.  Rather than `'((directory-files ...))`, try plain old `(directory-files ...)`, which will return the list you need.

Comment: @Dan That's the right solution, but doesn't address the *reason* that OP thought it wouldn't work: the list returned is printed as (x y z ...) and ... isn't one of the files.

Comment: @Joshua Taylor ... which is why it's only a comment and I +1'ed your answer. ;)

Comment: Confused by the edit: you've commented out the line that has `(directory-files ...)` and `mapcar`ed your function to a list of one file.

Comment: @Dan Sorry about that ; I edited the code as it is right now. It still doen't work, I'm now digging into the `px-bpm-parse` quoted function to try to understand what is going on. I'm tempted to accept Joshua's answer, since it at least got me past the predicate error.

Comment: All those `setq`s at the top of your function should be in a `let`, or else they'll be setting global variables.  `(let (u1 u2 u3 (project-dir "/var/www/html/microlabel.git/")) ...)`  Also, why are you `setq`ing `in-buf` at all, especially since you never use it?  Agree that you should probably accept the answer since it answers your original question; consider opening a new question if you're having trouble elsewhere in the function.

Comment: The (set-buffer ...) form isn't needed. (find-file ...) doesn't return a buffer name, but it does automatically switch to the buffer for the file you just found. Using (set-buffer ...) probably moves you to a new buffer that you don't want to be in.

Comment: By the way `(setq lst (cons x lst))` is usually written as `(push x lst)`.

Comment: @joshua `(push x lst)` +1 Good catch, thanks. Now I'm going to set the vars in a `let`, thank you for that one too, I do have a scope issue here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you evaluate a form and see a result of the form `(x y z ...)`, it's just *printed* in that way because the output is long.  The result is actually the list that you'd expect.  For instance,

```
(list 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13)
;=> (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 ...)
```

Yet, the last element of the list is what it should be:

```
(last (list 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13))
;=> (13)
```

Since `(directory-files "/path/" nil "\\.php$")` returns a list and the second argument to mapcar should be a list, you can make it the second argument:

```
(mapcar 'my-concat-function (directory-files "/path/" nil "\\.php$"))
```

Comment: OK about this "..." thing ; But Dan, the output of `(directory-files "/path/" nil "\\.php$")` = `("one.php" "two.php" "three.php" ...)` is technically different than what I'm actually passing to mapcar : `"one.php" "two.php" "three.php"` so I really needed a form (maybe using a lambda) that returns *exactly* this. The fact that the effect is different seem to corellate this, am I right?

Comment: @xaccrocheur I'm not Dan, but you've commented on my answer. The result of `(directory-files "/path/" nil "\\.php$")` a list of the files in the directory ending with `.php`. You can check that however you like (e.g., `(length (directory-files …))`).  When you see `("one.php" "two.php" "three.php" ...)`, Emacs is *printing* the first few elements of the list, and then printing  `...` to show that there are more elements. Just like the example where I listed the integers from 1 to 13; the result is a list of 1 to 13, but Emacs *prints* it, for convenience, as `(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 ...)`.

Comment: @xaccrocheur Please *try* the last line of code in my answer;  I'm pretty sure you'll find that it does what you expect it to.

Comment: The second argument to `mapcar` must be a list.  `mapcar` applies the first argument (your function) to each element of the list.  That is, it *maps* the function to each successive *car* (item at the front of the list) of the list.

Comment: @Joshua I got this "..." thing, OK. What I'm trying to understand here, Is about the structure of the list. Of course I tried the  code in your answer, as you can see is the edit. One other thing (other than the output of the code in EDIT when the unquoted `(directory-files ...) is un-commented`) that seem to indicate that `("one.php" "two.php" "three.php")` is *not* equal to `"one.php" "two.php" "three.php"` is that when I try it litterally, I get a `find-file-noselect: Wrong type argument: stringp` error ; thank you very much for your patience anyway. I'm going mad on this one.

Comment: @xaccrocheur I don't know what you mean in your comment.  Are you comparing `(mapcar 'foo "one.php" "two.php" "three.php")` and `(mapcar 'foo ("one.php" "two.php" "three.php"))`?  Neither of those is good.  The first is wrong because the second and following arguments to mapcar need to be lists, and you're passing strings.  The second is wrong because the second argument needs to be a list, so Emacs tries to evaluate `("one.php" "two.php" "three.php")` as a function call, but that won't work because `"one.php"` isn't the name of a function.  You need:

Comment: @xaccrocheur `(mapcar 'foo '("one.php" "two.php" "three.php"))` or `(mapcar 'foo (list "one.php" "two.php" "three.php"))`, so that the second argument to mapcar is a list.

Comment: Look: the following will find-file each of the following files and create new buffers for them if they don't already exist: `(mapcar #'find-file '("one.php" "two.php" "three.php"))`. Please trust the collective brain that @Joshua's answer is correct. The other problems are in the function itself, so you should open a different question.

Comment: Joshua, I get this. What you put in your last comment is how the function is working right now. What I need is to replace this proper list, with the output of `directory-files`. And I can't get it to return that : A list that mapcar accept.

Comment: @xaccrocheur directory-files returns a list of strings.  If you're getting an error with `(mapcar 'foo (directory-files ...))`, then it's because `foo` is causing an error, not mapcar.

Comment: @Dan @Joshua Figured it out, `(directory-files ...)` returns file names, not full paths. Really sorry.